# Scheduled task interrupt

Tags: scheduled-tasks, task

I would like to create a scheduled task wich should run every 20ms and modify the outputs based on some variable, but during this the program should run and check other things for example the inputs.
How can i do that the program run in "while True" section countinously, but when reach every end of 20ms, it goes to specified task and do it (it will be output setting) and when during the "while true" section one specified input is coming, this scheduled task should stop and when again is coming it should start.
Thank You for your help!

Comment: How is it 'coming'? If you start a scheduled task it can check for an 'input'... but how do you provide the input? You may want to consider building a windows service if this is on windows.

Comment: I start the program running, it just run, check the inputs and do something else (e.g. set one output led...), but when i give one specified input, it start this scheduled task what should run exactly every e.g. 20ms (what i set), here will be output settings based on something (i know how), and if this task has done the program continue from where it stopped because the scheduled task, and when 20ms elapse it again do the scheduled task and so on. I mainly now what the task and program should contain i just need how it can be inturrepted in every 20ms.

Answer (score 0):

I would think something as easy as a send key to simulate user input would cause the computer to cease to be idle. There is your interrupt

Or am I mistaken?

D
JPMC DEV/PRODSUPPORT